# Android: Unable to mount android phone although USB Debugging is enabled?

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu

I used to be able to mount the android phone, however after installing ADB, I can't seem to get the device mounted.

Some troubleshooting methods I tried:

1. installing mtpfs, and using mpt-detect, I got this error:

```
libmtp version: 1.1.10

Listing raw device(s)
   No raw devices found.

```

2. `lsusb` showed me the correct device is connected to my computer but the device remains unmounted.

Is there a way to let the device be mounted once again?

I am currently running Xubuntu LTS 16.04

I have already enabled USB Debugging on the android phone, but it still isn't connected. One thing I observed was the USB Debugging option was frozen, meaning it can't be disabled but is enabled permanently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: The problem was from using the MTP option in the android phone (note that I'm running Android 5.0).

Swipe down the notification widget from the top of your screen --> Tap for more USB options --> Select PTP

Now adb devices is showing something like:

```
List of devices attached 
LGD855a0000099  device
```